# How to adjust the size of a highlighted table with centered text?

Tags: latex

I need to write this exact same [table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AMGNp.jpg) in Latex (in the picture)

This is my code :

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{array,multirow,colortbl}
\usepackage{geometry}
 \geometry{
 a4paper,
 total={170mm,257mm},
 left=20mm,
 top=20mm,
 }
\begin{document}
\colorbox{lightgray}{%
\arrayrulecolor{white}
\begin{tabular}{p{2.2in} | p{2.1in}}
  \textbf{Signaleigenschaft} & \textbf{Mathematische Beschreibung} \\ \hline
  Explizit definiertes Signal & Funktionswert kann direkt abgelesen werden,\newline zum Beispiel\newline 
  $x\left(t\right)=10\cdot e^{-a\cdot t^{2} } \cdot \sin \left(b\cdot t\right)$ \\
  \end{tabular}%
}%end colorbox
\end{document}
```

[image: Image of table from code]

I obtain a small table and the text isn't like in the picture (centered etc..)

Comment: Please make a [mre] and not just a code fragment which we cannot compile

Comment: I am new with latex and i am writing a (long) dissertation, and the table is just a small part that's why i didn't write everything. I juste need to have the same exact table like in the picture i posted it doesn't have to be the same code i wrote.

Comment: We don't want your whole document, just a short but compilable example that would allow us to start working on your problem without having to debug all the missing stuff.

Comment: At the very least, you are still missing `\begin{document}` and, I must assume, `\begingroup` in order to make a reproducible example.

Comment: yes I added it and no the `\endgroup` was for `\colorbox{lightgray}{%`  for the highlight

Answer (score 1):

Centered text and applied sans serif font for both text and equation. Used `\parbox` with specific height and width to match spacing of "this exact same [table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AMGNp.jpg)".

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{array,multirow,colortbl}
\usepackage{geometry}
 \geometry{
 a4paper,
 total={170mm,257mm},
 left=20mm,
 top=20mm,
 }
\begin{document}
{
\scriptsize%
\sffamily%
\setlength{\fboxsep}{0pt}%
\colorbox{lightgray}{%
\arrayrulecolor{white}%
\begin{tabular}{| l | l |}
\hline
\parbox[c][0.28in][c]{2.5in}{\smallskip\centering\textbf{Signaleigenschaft}} & \parbox[c][0.28in][c]{2.5in}{\smallskip\centering\textbf{Mathematische Beschreibung}}\\ \hline
\parbox[c][0.64in][c]{2.5in}{\centering{Explizit definiertes Signal}} & \parbox[c][0.64in][c]{2.5in}{\centering{Funktionswert kann direkt abgelesen werden,\\zum Beispiel\\[3pt]$\mathsf{x\left(t\right)=10\cdot e^{-a\cdot t^{2} } \cdot \sin \left(b\cdot t\right)}$}}\\
\hline
\end{tabular}%
}%end colorbox
}
\end{document}
```

[image: Table]

Answer (score 0):

You could define a new, centred column type:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{array,multirow,colortbl}
\usepackage{geometry}
 \geometry{
 a4paper,
 total={170mm,257mm},
 left=20mm,
 top=20mm,
 }
 
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{#1}}
 
\begin{document}
\colorbox{lightgray}{%
\arrayrulecolor{white}
\begin{tabular}{C{2.2in} | C{2.1in}}
  \textbf{Signaleigenschaft} & \textbf{Mathematische Beschreibung} \\ \hline
  Explizit definiertes Signal & 
  Funktionswert kann direkt abgelesen werden,\par
  zum Beispiel\par 
  $x\left(t\right)=10\cdot e^{-a\cdot t^{2} } \cdot \sin \left(b\cdot t\right)$ \\
  \end{tabular}%
}%end colorbox
\end{document}
```

[image]